# compact finitely generated ring is second countable

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, topological-groups, topological-rings

An article I'm reading has this remark: "let R be a compact commutative ring and lets say that R contains a finitely generated dense subring S. so by the assumptions on S we have that R is second countable" 
I can't think of a proof for that remark, and would appreciate some insights on that problem. Also, I've gathered that its probably enough to show that R as a compact ring is first countable, should that even be true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. 1. Use Mathjax 2. Try to write a clear body

Comment: $S$ is finitely generated: in particular $S$ is countable. Now, $R$ has a countable dense subset, i.e. it is second countable. Are you aware of the fact that a finitely generated ring is countable?

Comment: @Crostul: It is clear enough that $R$ is separable, but a separable compact commutative ring does not have to be second countable.